# Smoothing the boundary of graph - gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, smoothing

In gnuplot, given  f and g two functions from plane to real line, I am going to plot  f  as g gets positive values. I have this code:

```
set xrange [-2:2]
set yrange [-2:2]
set isosamples 100,100 
unset grid 
unset key  
set view map
f(x,y) = x*x*exp(-x*x)*y*y*exp(-y*y)
g(x,y) = x**2  - y**2

h(x,y) = g(x,y)> 0 ? f(x,y) : 1/0

splot h(x,y) with pm3d
```

I obtain this:

[image]

I would like to smooth the boundary of this image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `g(x,y) = x**2 y**2` is not a valid function. What is missing there...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it should read `g(x,y) = x**2 - y**2`. Play with the parameters `samples` and `isosamples`. Check `help samples` and `help isosamples`.

For example:

```
set samples 300
set isosamples 300
```

**Result:**

[image]